# How can I display all dates between a specified date and week before in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How can I display all dates between a specified date and week before in mysql?

My goal is to show a weekly report.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT *

FROM payment

WHERE pay_date

BETWEEN '2014-05-15'

AND pay_date - INTERVAL 7 DAY ;
```

Comment: can you use php for this?

Comment: No I can't use php, thanks for your attention. I got my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT *
FROM payment
WHERE pay_date BETWEEN date('2014-05-15') - interval 7 day and date('2014-05-15');
```

Comment: yup, I want this. It works for me, Thanks alot =), stay blessed and keep helping =)